# Dificuldade em obter o valor do input radio por via desetruturação

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-eventos

**Boa tarde, Tenho esse código HTML e JavaScript.**

```
 <form data-form="form">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>
            <h2>Nova Transação</h2>
          </legend>
          <div class="input-group">
            <label for="description" class="sr-only">Descrição</label>
            <input type="text" 
              placeholder="Descrição da transação" 
              required 
              id="description" 
              data-form="description"
            >
          </div>
          <div class="input-group">
            <label for="amount" class="sr-only">Valor</label>
            <input type="number" 
              placeholder="Valor da transação" 
              required 
              id="amount"
              data-form="amount" step="0.5"
            >
          </div>
          <div class="radio-inputs input-group">
            
            <div class="expense-radio">
              <input type="radio" 
                name="transaction-type" 
                value="expense" id="expense" 
                data-form="transaction-type" 
                class="sr-only" 
                required
              >
              <label for="expense">Saídas</label>
            </div>
            <div class="income-radio">
              <input type="radio" 
                name="transaction-type" 
                value="income" id="income" 
                data-form="transaction-type" 
                class="sr-only" 
                required
              >
              <label for="income">Entradas</label>
            </div>
            
          </div>
          <div class="input-group">
            <label for="date" class="sr-only">Data</label>
            <input type="date" required id="date" data-form="date">
          </div>
          <div class="input-buttons input-group" >
            <span class="cancel" title="Cancelar" data-modal="close">Cancelar</span>
            <button type="submit">Salvar</button>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
  const form = {
    form: document.querySelector("[data-form='form']"),
    inDescription: document.querySelector("[data-form='description']"),
    inAmount: document.querySelector("[data-form='amount']"),
    inTransactionType: document.querySelector(
      "[data-form='transaction-type'][name='transaction-type']:checked"),
    inDate: document.querySelector("[data-form='date']"),

    gateValue() {
      const { inDescription, inAmount, inTransactionType, inDate } = form;
      return {
        description: inDescription.value,
        amount: inAmount.value,
        transactionType: inTransactionType.value,
        date: inDate.value,
      };
    },
  };

  form.form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(form.gateValue());
  });
```

**Com essa versão do JS, ele apresenta o seginte erro : app.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value').**

**Fazendo essa correção no código ele funciona:**

```
gateValue() {
      const { inDescription, inAmount, inTransactionType, inDate } = form;
      return {
        description: inDescription.value,
        amount: inAmount.value,
        transactionType: document.querySelector(
          "[data-form='transaction-type'][name='transaction-type']:checked"
        ).value,
        date: inDate.value,
      };
    }
```

Eu gostaria de saber o porquê desse comportamento?

Comment: `inTransactionType: document.querySelector("[data-form='transaction-type'][name='transaction-type']:checked")` - quando vc cria essa propriedade, provavelmente o transaction-type não está checked, por isso esse selector não encontra nada. Já se vc chama dentro de `gateValue`, na versão que funcionou ele  procura de novo pelo elemento (na versão que não funcionou ele não procura de novo). Dito isso, por que não usa o id dos elementos em vez do `data-`? O dataset [serve para outra coisa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

Answer (score -3):

Em vez de usar *querySelector* como foi usado **inTransactionType: document.querySelector(
"[data-form='transaction-type'][name='transaction-type']:checked")**,deve ser usado *getElementsByName* assim **inTransactionType: document.getElementsByName("transaction-type"),**

Criar uma função para pegar qual foi checked:

```
function radio(r) {
        for (var i = 0, length = r.length; i < length; i++) {
          if (r[i].checked) {
            return r[i];
          }
        }
      }

E na função gateValue chamar essa função transactionType: radio(inTransactionType).value
```

Answer (score -3):

Isso acontece pq quando a variável **form** é definida o usuário ainda não marcou nenhuma checkbox. Uma forma simples de resolver isso sem alterar muito o código é mover a constante **form** para dentro da função getValue e eliminando a necessidade do objeto:

```
const form = document.querySelector("[data-form='form']")
function gateValue() {
  const fields = {
    inDescription: document.querySelector("[data-form='description']"),
    inAmount: document.querySelector("[data-form='amount']"),
    inTransactionType: document.querySelector(
      "[data-form='transaction-type'][name='transaction-type']:checked"),
    inDate: document.querySelector("[data-form='date']"),
  }
  const { inDescription, inAmount, inTransactionType, inDate } = fields;
  return {
    description: inDescription.value,
    amount: inAmount.value,
    transactionType: inTransactionType.value,
    date: inDate.value,
  }
}

form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(gateValue());
});
```

Caso tenha interesse, existem outras formas mais simples de pegar o campos de um formulário como:

```
const form = document.querySelector("[data-form='form']")

form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData(event.target)
  const data = {}
  for (let [key, val] of formData.entries()) {
    Object.assign(data, { [key]: val })
  }

  console.log(data);
});
```

Único detalhe é que neste exemplo cada input precisa ter uma **name**.